# CISCO port tracing by LED light blinking

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, cdp, lldp

I work as IT technician,part of my job I have to trace the UTP cable to the switch port, I used for the a program called **WinCDP** by connecting to my laptop Ethernet port and it will tell me where is the port connected in the switch.the problem  we have many switches configured by AT&T and very secure that even **CDP** (CISCO discovery protocol) is off ,so I'm unable to trace the cable using winCDP.

**is there any network software that can make the port on the switch side blink(Flash) in special way that will help me recognize the port I'm connected to ?** I don't have access to the switch because I'm a contractor for another company.

Comment: You could write a script that disables/enables the NIC on the PC so you can see it flash on the switch directly.. Or you could get somebody to plug the cable in and out while you are looking at the switch

Comment: @FrederikNielsen not a good solution if you have many cable...my Ethernet port will be damaged by disable/enable.